# Problems Displaying Image Using APParallaxHeader

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a view titled HomeViewController that I embedded inside a navigation view controller. Inside the view, I dragged a table view and linked it using IBOutlet. I added the necessary code from the [APParallaxHeader](https://github.com/apping/APParallaxHeader) library, and imported it into my project using cocoapods.

However I'm currently having problems displaying the image. Even though the space is created, the actually image doesn't display. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

This is what my .h/.m files look like:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIScrollView+APParallaxHeader.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSArray *menu;
    IBOutlet UITableView *menuTableView;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *menuTableView;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize menuTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    menu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2,", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", nil];

    [self.menuTableView addParallaxWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ParallaxImage.jpg"] andHeight:160];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [menu count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: plz check your file name ParallaxImage.jpg  or ParallaxImage.jpeg or use .png instead of .jpg

Comment: Thanks Samir, but I made sure. In fact I even tried Default.png and again nothing. I removed it and re-added the image and again nothing.

Comment: @interface HomeViewController : UITableViewController  your base class must be UITableViewController controller not uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem. Hopefully it helps others in the future.

Turns out that my tableview was stored inside another view, within my main view controller. By deleting that view and making the following changes, I was able to get it working:

[image]